# How to use XPathNavigator to read expect node's value in InforPath C# language?

Tags: c#, infopath, xpathnavigator

I am working on Infopath with C# language and I try many time to get expect node's value use XPathNavigator. But the result didn't as my expect. I have xml script bellow:

```
  <my:AuditInformation>
<my:AuditQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>85</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Loadout Note No.</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>1</my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>3</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText>eg: 5AZA123456</my:QuestionTooltipText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>87</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Shipment Number</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue>2</my:QuestionAnswerValue>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>1</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>88</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Destination Port</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>3</my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>3</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>100</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Container ID</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>56456</my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>3</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText>Container ID number</my:QuestionTooltipText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>101</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Container 2</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>6</my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>3</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>102</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Container 3</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>7</my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>3</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
  <my:AuditInformationQuestions>
    <my:QuestionID>322</my:QuestionID>
    <my:QuestionText>Exporting KR, RE, IN</my:QuestionText>
    <my:QuestionAnswerTextbox/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
    <my:QuestionTypeID>2</my:QuestionTypeID>
    <my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
      <my:AuditQuestionYes>false</my:AuditQuestionYes>
      <my:AuditQuestionNo>false</my:AuditQuestionNo>
    </my:AuditQuestionsYesNoSection>
    <my:QuestionTooltipText/>
    <my:QuestionAnswerDropList>0</my:QuestionAnswerDropList>
  </my:AuditInformationQuestions>
</my:AuditQuestions>
```

I want to get two value from two node:

```
<my:QuestionText>Container ID</my:QuestionText>
<my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>56456</my:QuestionAnswerTextbox>
```

Can you provide me how to do that, If you can, please guide me or give me another way or solution to do that?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are repeating nodes in that XML, so you need to use XPathNodeIterator and loop to go through those nodes. Try this:

```
XPathNodeIterator auditInformationQuestionsNode = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().Select("my:AuditQuestions/my:AuditInformationQuestions", NamespaceManager);
foreach (XPathNavigator node in auditInformationQuestions)
{
   string questionTextValue = node.SelectSingleNode("my:QuestionText", NamespaceManager).Value;
   string questionAnswerTextboxValue = node.SelectSingleNode("my:QuestionAnswerTextbox", NamespaceManager).Value;
}
```

You will get what you need inside those variables: questionTextValue and questionAnswerTextbox.

Hope this will be helpful.

Note: I suppose you provide only part of the XML, so your path to my:AuditInformationQuestions node may be different. You need to use full path there to get it.